# What framework used in WSO2 Emm?

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I have struggle to work with source code in wso2 emm. I don't know how to setup wso2 emm in eclipse?, What framework they used? And how to generate the wso2 emm bundle? Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 EMM used [carbon framework](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/). EMM is not worked with eclipse. It is a product you can use to control mobile devices. You can get the [emm product source](https://github.com/wso2/product-emm) and build it using maven. After you build the product, you can find the product zip in /modules/distribution/target folder. find more information how product works on [the documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/WSO2+Enterprise+Mobility+Manager)

Comment: Finally Thank you! Very helpful. And i have one more doubt. how can i work with emm product source code? I have noticed some minor bugs in last emm release 2.1.0. So I like fix those bugs. Please give some suggestion.

Comment: open the project in intelij idea or eclipse and solve those bugs..:)

Comment: I had steup the project in intelij IDE but how to run the product for test?

Comment: just maven clean install run all the integration tests.